# Reversing directed graph in Common Lisp

Tags: graph, common-lisp

The input to this function is a directed graph. For example, ((A B C) (B C) (C D)) means that there is a directed edge from A to B, A to C, B to C and C to D.

What I'm trying to do is reverse all the edges in the graphs. So with the example above, I'm trying to get an output like ((C B A) (B A) (D C)).

This is the code I've written so far:

```
(defun reverse-net (net)
  (let (new-net)
    (dolist (obj net)
      (dolist (st (cdr obj))
        (let (cur (assoc st new-net))  
          (if cur
              (push (cons (car obj) cur) new-net)
            (push (list st (car obj)) new-net)))))
    new-net))
```

Unfortunately, in the code `assoc` (line 5) is always returning nil.  The output I'm getting is ((D C) (C B) (C A) (B A)), which has not merged (C B) and (C A).
Please help me spot the problem in the function.

Comment: `(cur (assoc st new-net))` is wrong. There is a level of parentheses missing.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that the posted code is missing some parentheses: `(let (cur (assoc st new-net))` --> `(let ((cur (assoc st new-net)))`. SBCL won't even compile the posted code, instead issuing the error message: ***error: The LET binding spec (ASSOC ST NEW-NET) is malformed.***

The second problem is that when `cur` is found in `new-net`, an enlarged list of nodes is pushed onto `new-net`, but the old one is not removed. One solution to this problem is to remove the found list of nodes before pushing the updated list onto `new-net`.

The third problem is that this line: `(push (cons (car obj) cur) new-net)` is consing nodes onto the *front* of the nodes lists. You need to append these to the *back* of the lists since the first node in the list is the from-node, while the other nodes are to-nodes.

```lisp
(defun reverse-net (net)
  (let (new-net)
    (dolist (obj net)
      (dolist (st (cdr obj))
        (let ((cur (assoc st new-net)))  
          (cond (cur
                 (setf new-net (remove (car cur) new-net :key #'car))
                 (push (append cur (list (car obj))) new-net))
                (t
                 (push (list st (car obj)) new-net))))))
    new-net))
```

```
CL-USER> (reverse-net '((a b c) (b c) (c d)))
((D C) (C A B) (B A))
```

### An Alternate Implementation

The posted code isn't written in an overly clear style; better names for identifiers would help. But one could also rethink the solution a bit to add some clarity.

A function that decomposes a list of nodes representing a compound edge could be written, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun decompose (edge)
  (let ((pred (car edge)))
    (mapcar (lambda (succ) (list pred succ))
            (cdr edge))))
```

This function could be used in another function that takes a directed graph with compound edges and reverses it, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun reverse-digraph (digraph)
  (mapcar #'reverse
          (apply #'append (mapcar #'decompose digraph))))
```

With these functions you can verify that they function as expected, and in some cases they may give useful output in and of themselves:

```
CL-USER> (decompose '(a b c))
((A B) (A C))
CL-USER> (decompose '(b c))
((B C))
CL-USER> (reverse-digraph '((a b c) (b c) (c d)))
((B A) (C A) (C B) (D C))
```

Above it can be easily seen that `reverse-digraph` produces the correct set of directed edges. Another function could be written to take a directed graph represented by simple edges and return a representation using compound edges, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun reverse-net (digraph)
  (let (collected)
    (dolist (edge (reverse-digraph digraph) collected)
      (let* ((pred (car edge))
             (succ (cdr edge))
             (found (assoc pred collected)))
        (if found
            (nsubstitute (append found succ) pred collected :key #'car)
            (push edge collected))))))
```

This function returns a result equivalent to the earlier result:

```
CL-USER> (reverse-net '((a b c) (b c) (c d)))
((D C) (C A B) (B A))
```

Answer (score 0):

The zeroth problem with your code is that it is written as if it was 1956 and data abstraction had not been invented: everything is lists and `car` and `cd` and it's totally opaque what is going on.

Instead lets invent an conceptual type (which may or may not be actually a distinct type in the system):

- a *digraph* is a list (just an ordinary list) of *digraph-nodes*
- a *digraph-node* is an object with a *label* and a list of *target labels* which are the labels of its target nodes.

Note that nodes have target *labels* not nodes: this makes digraphs slower to process but much easier to build.

Well, we could either just write a bunch of functions which wrap up the representation of nodes as conses:

```
(defun make-digraph-node (label &optional (targets '()))
  (cons label target-labels))

(defun digraph-node-label (node)
  (car node))

(defun digraph-node-target-labels (node)
  (cdr node))

(defun (setf digraph-node-target-labels) (new node)
  (setf (cdr node) new))
```

Or we could just define a structure:

```
(defstruct (digraph-node
            (:constructor make-digraph-node (label &optional (target-labels '()))))
  label
  target-labels)
```

None of the code below cares.

So lets write functions to turn lists into digraphs and digraphs into lists:

```
(defun list->digraph (list)
  (mapcar (lambda (d)
            (make-digraph-node (car d) (cdr d)))
          list))

(defun digraph->list (digraph)
  (mapcar (lambda (n)
            (cons (digraph-node-label n) (digraph-node-target-labels n)))
          digraph))
```

And now we can write a function to reverse a digraph easily:

```
(defun reverse-digraph (digraph)
  (let ((reversed-digraph '()))
    (dolist (node digraph reversed-digraph)
      (let ((label (digraph-node-label node)))
        (dolist (target-label (digraph-node-target-labels node))
          (pushnew label
                   (digraph-node-target-labels
                    (or (find target-label reversed-digraph :key #'digraph-node-label)
                        (car (push (make-digraph-node target-label)
                                   reversed-digraph))))))))))
```

And now

```
> (digraph->list (reverse-digraph (list->digraph '((A B C) (B C) (C D)))))
((d c) (c b a) (b a))
```

Other representations of digraphs are easily possible, of course: the important thing is to use names for accessors, constructors &c in the code which *make sense in terms of the conceptual objects you are dealing with*.